# ¿Como puedo obtener un valor n de un campo de texto con js?

Tags: javascript, html

soy nuevo con js, esto es lo que sucede.

### tengo esta función:

que es donde recojo el valor del cajón para saber cuantos puntos hay que hallar

```
function puntos(npuntos) {
    if (npuntos >= 2) {

        document.getElementById("number_punt").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("cont_recoger_puntos").style.display = 'block';

    }else{
        alert("Ingrese por favor un valor valido!");
    }
}
```

---

### y tengo esta otra:

[image: Funcion numero 2]

---

este es mi problema: [image: Problema]

pido la cantidad de puntos a los cuales se les quiere hallar su respectiva distancia y luego los valores de cada punto, pero si ingreso mas de dos 2 puntos, como por ejemplo 4, no me deja dar valores a los puntos entre 1 y 4 (a los puntos 2 y 3) y me salta directamente al ultimo punto (en este caso punto 4) para que le ingrese sus respectivos valores. no se que estoy haciendo mal, disculpen mi ignorancia frente al tema.

Comment: creo tienes que formular el codigo de otra manera

Comment: Reformula tu pregunta no es muy entendible

Comment: @GermanAviles se mas claro en lo que deseas conseguir.